# Hikari and MySQL documentation inconsistency

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hikaricp

I'm switching my Spring Boot+MySQL connection from Tomcat-based to HikariCP. 
I read the documentation and I got confused. [Here](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#configuration-knobs-baby) they say:

> MysqlDataSource is known to be broken, use jdbcUrl configuration
>   instead. [image]

At the same time, at [recomended settings site](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/MySQL-Configuration) they say the opposite:

```
In order to get the best performance out of MySQL, these are some of our recommended settings. 

dataSourceClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
dataSource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/database
dataSource.user=test
...
```

Did I miss something? I used MysqlDataSource and it seems to work, whats the deal here?

Comment: The first is the correct one. There is a bug in the `MysqlDataSource` and hence for the time being you are suggested to use the `url` option instead. See https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/754 for more information on the bug.

Comment: can you give an example of such url?  Is this what you mean:     hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db");